# Drop all tables sql developer

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, drop-table

I have tables that names start with "TBL_*", but I can not **drop** all of  them by single command.

how can I drop this tables?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can write a script, specifically, loop, in which you select Table_name from user_tables and iterate this loop , and use "execute immediate" command to drop them.

But I would suggest this - in sql tool do

```
  select 'drop table ' || table_name || ';' from user_tables where table_name like 'TBL_%'
```

Then you copy output of this query and paste into your sql editor, and execute.
Remember, if sql+ is your editor, if you paste them all, they will start execute. May be you want to use notepad to review and edit it first.

But you can't just drop more than one table in one single command. 
Check this link for other options associated with drop table http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_9003.htm

Answer (score 15):

```
BEGIN

  --Bye Tables!
  FOR i IN (SELECT ut.table_name
              FROM USER_TABLES ut) LOOP
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'drop table '|| i.table_name ||' CASCADE CONSTRAINTS ';
  END LOOP;

END;
```

Comment: I described this technique in my original answer >3 years ago. And I pointed that it can be dangerous sometimes when working with data http://stackoverflow.com/a/18030453/1704458

Comment: This gets a downvote, because the user *specifically asked* for only tables starting with "TBL_" - this would delete all!

Comment: I am giving vote up because it removes tables without fk complaints unlike the post marked as answered. Shame for oracle to have no such functionality in the app. I often use migrator and drop all tables when debbugin it.